# `UIWebView` back and forward with `UIGestureRecognizer`

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, uigesturerecognizer

I have added a `UIGestureRecognizer`to a `UIWebView` to go back and forward.
But my question is how can I call this `UIGestureRecognizer`if the user swipe from the very left of the screen to the middle (`goBack`) or from the very right of the screen to the middle (`goForward`) and not if the user swipe from right to left e.g. in the middle of the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new class available in IOS 7 for this purpose. It is UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer. See the documentation for that class. It is a subclass of UIPanGestureRecognizer.

You will need to attach it to your UIWebView. I was able to drag and drop a UIPanGestureRecognizer on to a UIWebView in Interface Builder and change the class to UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer in the Identity Inspector Class drop-down.

Comment: I actually did not get the 'UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer' working with the 'UIWebView'. I had a solution that worked for Swipe, so I am sticking with that. I just connected the following to my Swipe gesture recognizer '- (IBAction)didSwipeRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if (self.webView.canGoBack)
    {
        [self.webView goBack];
    }
    else
    {
        [self myLoadHTMLMethod];
    }
}' I just needed to move on after getting stuck. I know there can be interference between gesture recognizers, so I had removed the swipe while I was working on the screen edge.